# No menus after installation

Tags: interface

[image]No menus shown after installation

I started getting interested in Blender, so I installed it and wanted to mess with it. After downloading and installing blender, there was no menus at all. I tried restarting blender, doing a factory reset on Blender, restarting my pc and reinstalling Blender, but nothing worked. However I can still interact with the menus even though they're not visible, also for some reason the preferences windows is broken/glitched and potentially more of them are also broken

Comment: Could you have wrong drivers version ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to https://blender.stackexchange.com/. This is either a bug, or a problem to be solved on the side of the operating system or driver. In both cases, the question is unfortunately outside the scope of this platform.